# C++ structured bindings not working with bitset

Tags: c++, c++17

I was writing a function that needed to return multiple variables, one of them being a bitset. Then I encountered some strange compilation error.

I tried different compilers, they all produce an error, albeit with different messages.

I tried googling, it seems that it has something to do with public and private inheritance. But I don't think it should affect this piece of code in any way.

The simplified code (C++17) looks like this:

```cpp
#include <bitset>
auto f() { return bitset<100>(); }

int main()
{
    auto [a] = f();
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove the square brackets (i.e. remove the structured binding and use normal auto), it works.

The error messange is as follows:

source.cpp: In function 'int main()':

source.cpp:9:18: error: 'std::_Base_bitset<2>' is an inaccessible base of 'std::bitset<100>'

```
9 |     auto [a] = f();

  |                  ^
```

Compiler returned: 1

So my question is: Is this expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong? Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I'm curious what you wanted to achieve with this / what you hoped would happen instead? Your function _doesn't_ return multiple values; it literally just returns a bitset. One bitset.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three kinds of types that work with structured bindings:

- language arrays
- types that opt-in to the tuple protocol (i.e. they provide specializations of `tuple_size` and `tuple_element` and overloads of `get`)
- types for which all of their members are public members of the same base class (~ish)

`std::bitset` is none of these. Its specification does not say what its members are, and it does not provide an opt-in to the tuple protocol. Hence, it does not work with structured bindings. It is expected that `auto [a] = f();`  would fail.

If anything, why would a `bitset<100>` only provide a single binding? I would expect that if it provided bindings, it would provide 100 of them...

Comment: I got it. I need to specify that it's a tuple, by returning make_tuple(bitset<100>()). Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, don't make a `tuple<bitset>`. That's just weird. Instead, stop using structured bindings inappropriately.

Comment: @FallingStar That makes no sense. Why? Just wrote `auto a = f();`

Answer (score 6):

This is… not what [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) are for.

You have *one* bitset.

Your approach probably triggers the rule of SBs that can bind to data members; but, as you've discovered, this is not something useful or supported, and each implementation (with its slightly different code) is yielding a different symptom of that.

Simply use this single return value in the usual manner.

Comment: I was oversimplyfing the code, I actually needed to return a few arrays, one of them being a bitset.

Comment: A bitset is not an array.